# Determining if a sequence is a valid DNA sequence

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, for-loop, dna-sequence

I'm attempting to write this program that reads in a sequence into a string variable, called `sequence`, and finds out if `sequence` contains a valid DNA sequence or not. **I want to use a single `for` and one `if-elif-else`statement to determine whether the sequence is valid DNA or not.**
This is what I have written so far:

```
sequence = input("Please enter a sequence: ").upper()
valid_dna = "ACGT"
sequence = sequence.replace(" ", "")

common=0
for eachletter in sequence:
    if eachletter in valid_dna:
        common +=1

print("This is a valid dna sequence")

elif sequence != valid_dna:
    print("This is not a valid DNA sequence")

else:
    print()
```

I don't know what to add after `elif`, because what I added after `elif` it returns `Syntax error`.

I originally had

```
sequence = input().upper()
sequence= input("Please enter a sequence:  ")
```

which didn't work well together, thank you to VHarisop for pointing it out!

Update:
This is what I have now, and it works!

```
sequence = input().upper()
valid_dna = "ACGT"
sequence = sequence.replace(" ", "")

for i in sequence:
    if i in valid_dna:
            count = 1
    else:
            count=0
if count==1:
    print("This is a valid DNA sequence.") 
else:
    print("This is an invalid DNA sequence")
```

Comment: What does it do - important to tell what behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have:

```
sequence = input().upper()
# irrelevant code
sequence= input("Please enter a sequence:  ")
```

This will ask for input two times, turning everything you type to uppercase the first time and leaving it untouched the second, which will obviously result in erroneous behaviour. I would recommend keeping only:

```
sequence = input('Please enter a sequence: ').upper()
```

and then using a generator expression to check validity.

Actually, there is no need to keep a separate string for non-valid characters. Just do:

```
valid_dna = 'ACGT'
sequence = input('Please enter a sequence: ').upper()

# will print True if every character in the sequence belongs to valid_dna
print(all(i in valid_dna for i in sequence))
```

Here, the generator expression `(i in valid_dna for i in sequence)` will return True for every character of the sequence that belongs to `valid_dna` and False for every character that does not. The built-in function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) will return True only if every value generated by the expression is True.

If you want a proper message, you can simply check the return value of the expression and print accordingly:

```
condition = all(i in valid_dna for i in sequence)
print('Valid sequence') if condition else print('Invalid sequence')
```

Comment: If I add spaces in my `sequence`, then it will print `Invalid sequence`, if I want it to still print true (with spaces), should I add `sequence= sequence.strip(' ')`?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I added `sequence = sequence.replace(" ", "")` and it stripped off all the white space!

Answer (score 6):

I would just use `all` and a generator expression

```
>>> valid = 'ACTG'

>>> s1 = 'ATAGCGGCAT'
>>> all(i in valid for i in s1)
True

>>> s2 = 'ABCDEFHI'
>>> all(i in valid for i in s2)
False
```

If you have to use a `for` loop and `if` statements because this is a homework requirement, you can use a similar idea

```
def validSequence(s):
    valid = 'ACTG'
    for letter in s:
        if letter not in valid:
            return False
    return True

>>> validSequence('ATAGCGGCAT')
True
>>> validSequence('ABCDEFHIJK')
False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    char_invalid = ''
    for char in dna:
        if char not in 'ATCG':
            char_invalid = char_invalid + char
    return not bool (char_invalid)
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.